# Answering "Amen" etc after putting on tefillin shel rosh?

Tags: halacha, tefilin, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, hefsek-interruption, amen

For a sefardi that only says one beracha on tefillin, can "Amen" and "Amen - yehe scheme raba..." be answered immediately after putting on the shel rosh but before tying the shel yad around the fingers? Or must he wait until the tefillin is on completely?

Since the shel rosh has been put on as well, is it considered that the beracha has been fully utilized or is there still the aspect of tying the strings around the finger that is needed to be completed before an interruption is allowed?

Comment: Why does only saying one bracha matter?

Comment: @Daniel the single beracha covers both shel yad and shel rosh -- being the case you are not allowed to interrupt the process before everything the beracha was intended for is completed.

Comment: @AniYodeya Ashkenazim also can't interrupt before everything their brachot were intended for is completed. What does 1 vs 2 have to do with it?

Comment: Why is it any different if he says two brachas?

Comment: @Daniel, DoubleAA, maybe the edited second paragraph can help. If not let me know and I'll remove the entire part about the beracha.

Comment: Ani Yodeya, don't remove the part about the _b'racha_. The issue of _b'racha_ is important. They're merely picking on your specifying that the question is according to _S'faradim_. The same issue would apply to _Ashk'nazim_, as the _b'racha_ that _Ashk'nazim_ make on the _shel yad_ applies to the _shel rosh_ also and therefore its "scope" (if you will) extends as long as a _S'faradi_'s _b'racha_'s "scope". But it's fine: nothing's actually wrong with the question: you're entitled to ask according to _S'faradim_ only, and, indeed, it's conceivable a priori that the practice of what to [cont'd]

Comment: [cont'd] do (the answer to your question) is different for _S'faradim_ and for _Ashk'nazim_.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you for sure but here is some info that may help.

Concerning the hephsek between the shel yad and the shel rosh, the Ben Ish Chai is stringent not to interrupt for Kadish or Kedusha between the two even when NO bracha is made, such as when putting on Rabbeinu Tam. See his halachos at the end of parshas Vayeira, shana alef, siman 26. So apparently making a bracha or not should not matter.

Concerning the actual wrapping of the retzuos, see there siman 16, he is of the opinion that WHILE wrapping one should say the psukim 'vi'eirastich li etc'. This would imply that there Is no problem of hephsek. This is not a perfect proof because you can always say those psukim are connected to the laying of tephilin, but you can decide.